# How to fix font rendering in different browsers?

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

I have a strange problem: the same part of text with the same custom font looks different in all browsers. You can see some examples for text from page http://staceydogs.ru/about this: https://yadi.sk/d/YjWXPSZHZ8qBH (Safari example is good, Chrome renders fonts not right).

How can I fix the behaviour of browser's font rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` everywhere where you define your font-family. I don't have a Apple pc so I can't test it for you, but I am sure this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This option changes some symbols of the font and colour of text (and I think that it's very strange) in Chrome, but the size of symbols doesn't change (text from example takes 4 rows in Chrome and 3 rows in Safari). As a result the text looks much better, but its view still depends from browser :(